# Parse XML file in PHP using DOM

Tags: php, xml, parsing, dom

i need to parse multiple XML files and put parsed data to database.

Structure of xml looks like this

```
<npc ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
  <race>DATA</race>
  <sex>DATA</sex>
  <parameters>
          <param ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
          <param ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
          <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
          <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
  </parameters>
  <equipment ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
  <acquire ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
  <stats ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
      <vitals ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
      <attack ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
      <defence ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
          <attribute>
              <defence ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
          </attribute>
      </defence>
  </stats>
  <skilllist>
      <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
      <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
      <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
      <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
  </skilllist>
  <excrteffect>DATA<excrteffect>
</npc>
```

My current code looks like this:

```
$allFiles = scandir($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "mydir");
$files = array_diff($allFiles, array('.', '..'));
$doc = new DOMDocument();

foreach($files as $filename) {

    $xml_file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "mydir" . $filename, FILE_TEXT);
    $doc->loadXML($xml_file);
    $items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('npc');

    for ($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {

        $xml_file = file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "mydir" . $filename, FILE_TEXT); 
        $doc->loadXML($xml_file);

        $Id = $doc->getElementsByTagName("npc")->item($i)->getAttribute("id");
        $Name = $doc->getElementsByTagName("npc")->item($i)->getAttribute("name");
        $Lvl = $doc->getElementsByTagName("npc")->item($i)->getAttribute("level");
        $Type = $doc->getElementsByTagName("npc")->item($i)->getAttribute("type");
        $Title = $doc->getElementsByTagName("npc")->item($i)->getAttribute("title");

        $Sex = $doc->getElementsByTagName("sex")->item($i)->nodeValue;
        $Race = $doc->getElementsByTagName("race")->item($i)->nodeValue;
     }
}
```

It works fine for data that i've already coded, now i need get the rest. How can i get attributes from rest of xml? For example how to get attributes from

```
npc > stats > defence > attribute > defence
```

Comment: Although there is a certain amount of learning curve, I would suggest learning some XPath as this will make your code much more concise.

Comment: Thanks for advice, gonna do it in free time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate the same way you did first. Each `getElementsByTagName()` will return a `DOMNodeList` that will the same way as you did at first. If you are sure you structure will be the same as you have here, then use this code, otherwise you need to iterate with foreach or for:

```
<?php

$xml_file = '<npc ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
<race>DATA</race>
<sex>DATA</sex>
<parameters>
        <param ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
        <param ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
        <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
        <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
</parameters>
<equipment ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
<acquire ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
<stats ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
    <vitals ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
    <attack ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
    <defence ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">
        <attribute>
            <defence ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3="">150</defence>
        </attribute>
    </defence>
</stats>
<skilllist>
    <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
    <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
    <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
    <skill ATT1="" ATT2="" ATT3=""/>
</skilllist>
<excrteffect>DATA</excrteffect>
</npc>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml_file);

$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('npc');
$stats = $items[0]->getElementsByTagName('stats');
$defence1 = $stats[0]->getElementsByTagName('defence');
$attribute = $defence1[0]->getElementsByTagName('attribute');
$defence2 = $attribute[0]->getElementsByTagName('defence');

var_dump($defence2[0]->nodeValue);
```